# Total Orders and Total Revenue

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, datepart

I want total orders and total revenue on 31st dec. But in this query so many duplicate values are there..

```
select *
from Orderdetails od inner join
     OrderProducts op
     on od.orderid=op.orderid inner join
     addonProducts ap
     on ap.addonproductid=op.productid  
where od.DeliveryDate between convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(50), '12/31/2014',101)) and
                              convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(50), '01/02/2015',101))  and
      Datepart(Month, od.DeliveryDate) = '12' and DATEPART(DAY,od.DeliveryDate) = '31' and
      od.TransactionId is not null and ap.addonCategoryId='1002'
```

Comment: You need aggregates with group by

Comment: ya..  but in the result i got so many duplicate values like...  customerid:50109
48086
50109
48086
50109
48086
50109
36469

Comment: what about using select distinct?

Comment: can you share share sample data

Comment: I want unique values and using aggregate functions...

Comment: OrderID CustomerId CustomerFirstName DeliveryDate TransactionId
GA12272014063628703 50109 Vidhya 12/31/2014 9D694287NA7954709
GA12312014132804290 48086 Kalyan Chakravarthy 12/31/2014 232fb618642060ef6cb4
GA12272014063628703 50109 Vidhya 12/31/2014 9D694287NA7954709

Comment: What do you want to group by - or do you just want a total for the day? Where is the price that the revenue is based on held - in orderproducts or Orderdetails? Is there a one-to-many relationship between orderproducts and addonproducts? Currently we need to be second-guessing your database schema to try to answer...

Comment: @SushmaSatya SO has a [handy guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to provide useful sample data.  Try following these tips and you'll likely find it's easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any schema details:

```
select count(distinct od.transactionId), sum(op.productprice)
from Orderdetails od inner join
 OrderProducts op
 on od.orderid=op.orderid inner join
 addonProducts ap
 on ap.addonproductid=op.productid  
where od.DeliveryDate between '2014-12-31' and '2015-01-01'and
  od.TransactionId is not null and ap.addonCategoryId='1002'
```

This will give you the order total and revenue for the day assuming:

- there is no need to group by any particular columns (such as product name or date)
- a one-to-many relationship between Orderdetails and OrderProducts
- a one-to-one relationship between OrderProducts and addonProducts with a given addonCategoryId
- a productprice column in OrderProducts from which the revenue is derived

Comment: As I said I was making a whole load of assumptions. Are my assumptions correct? How do you know the actual count is 46? What query are you using to ascertain this?

Comment: ya in my backed panel  i checked it.. its showing 46.

Comment: Backed panel? What is that? Can you post the query you used to get the 46 orders?